# Gradient descent with no analytical function f(x)

Tags: gradient-descent, numerical-models

I find myself in the position of wanting to minimize a numerical function f(a,b) with respect to a and b for which I do not have a the analytical form f(a,b). All I have is f(a,b) for many values of a and b. Is it still possible to do a gradient descent to minimize f with respect to a and b?

$w_{k+1} = w_{k} - \alpha_{k} \nabla f(w) $

with w the vector holding a and b.

Or is numerical gradient descent impossible?

Comment: Can you calculate gradients of $f$ with respect to parameters? If no, then you are missing the key component.

Answer (score 2):

I suspect what you are after is not gradient descent *per se*, but any form of optimisation algorithm. [There are articles on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derivative-free_optimization) about derivative-free optimisation, that may be of use.

You also need to be able to find new values of $f(a,b)$. If you can't do that, your best guess at optimising $f$ is taking the minimum value for $f$ that you've found so far. (Unless of course the values for $f$ can be clearly and unambiguously extrapolated from the data you already have.)